# Tell that process is not in the background?

Tags: python, taskmanager

I'm writing a script that starts a process (UiPath.Executor.exe) unless it's already running:

```
 while True:
        process_names = (process_names.name() for process_names in psutil.process_iter()) # <- task mngr processes
        if "UiPath.Executor.exe" not in process_names: #then run it
```

The problem is I'm on a server with multiple users who might be running the same process at the same time, and the process shows up in the Background processes of the Task Manager. So the script thinks it's already running.

When my version of it runs, it runs in Apps section of the task manager, not  Background processes.
[image]

Is there a way to differentiate between Apps and Background processes in my script?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check the uses of the process? Validate that against the logged in user

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: process_names .username()